# How to always show scrollbar

Tags: android, scrollview

The scrollbar in my scrollview is only visible when I start scrolling.
How can I always show it?

Answer (score 632, accepted):

As of now the best way is to use `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in xml which is equivalent to `ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);` in java code.

Comment: for ListView didn't work, but this worked: `view.setScrollBarFadeDuration(0);`

Comment: so the right and accepted answer should be @Tanmay Mandal  answer (`setScrollBarFadeDuration(0)`), because `setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)` doesn't work everywhere

Comment: or it stops works for example because of like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673848/7767664 (onStop, onStart again and faield), so `setScrollBarFadeDuration(0);` is more reliable

Comment: One thing to note is the scrollbar will not show when the view is not scrollable ✓

Comment: I needed this on my recyclerview to both have the bar and always see it
`android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:fadeScrollbars="false"`

Comment: I like to have the scrollbar always showing on fullscreen text to so users know there is more text to see offscreen, which otherwise may not be obvious to many users even if bottom row of text is clipped.

Comment: setScrollbarFadingEnabled causes null pointer exception for me on opening the page, setScrollBarFadeDuration(0) has no effect.

Answer (score 62):

Setting the `android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"` will do the trick.

Comment: available in sdk 16 as a java method

Answer (score 56):

There are 4 ways:

- From Java code: `ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);`
- From XML code: `android:fadeScrollbars="false"`
- From Java code: `myView.setScrollBarFadeDuration(0)`
- From XML code: `android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"`

Simple as that!

Answer (score 24):

Don't forget to add `android:scrollbars="vertical"` along with `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` or it won't show at all in some cases.

Answer (score 23):

Style your scroll bar Visibility, Color and Thickness like this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/recycler_bg"

        <!--Show Scroll Bar-->
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="50000"

        <!--Scroll Bar thickness-->
        android:scrollbarSize="4dp"

        <!--Scroll Bar Color-->
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorSecondaryText"/>
```

Hope it help save some time.

Answer (score 13):

Try this as the above suggestions didn't work for me when I wanted to do this for a TextView:

```
TextView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Good Luck.

Comment: @user924 sure, but that answer was posted 10 days after my comment

Answer (score 11):

Try `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"` for vertical.
and Try `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"` for horizontal

Answer (score 11):

Simple and easy. Add this  attribute to the `ScrollBar`:

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Or you can do this in [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```
scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Or in [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin):

```
scrollView.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 9):

Since neither of the above worked for me, here's what did: `android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="500000"`

Answer (score 9):

`android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"` sometimes does not work after I exit from the apps and start again. So I add `gallery.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);` to the activity and it works!

Answer (score 8):

These two together worked for me:

```
android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. The bar had the same background color. Try:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 4):

setVertical* helped to make vertical scrollbar always visible programmatically

```
scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
scrollView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting this will do the trick. Change the @drwable for own style.

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll"`
```

Answer (score -1):

use awakenScrollBars() awake scrollbar draw.