# How to show native Android scrollbar when scrolling but disable using the scrollbar in a view?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I have a custom view that extends AbsListView. I want to be able to display the scrollbar to give users a sense of position within a list, but disable users from being able to use the scrollbar to scroll. I have been able to display the scrollbar properly, but can not figure out how to disable the scrollbar from being usable/touchable. Any suggestions?

To be clear, I do not want to disable scrolling in general, I want to disable scrolling through use of the scrollbar, YET still show the scrollbar when the view is scrolled by other means.

Comment: check this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702502/how-to-always-show-scrollbar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable scrolling in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)

Comment: I am not trying to disable scrolling in general. I want to disable users from being able to scroll WITH the scrollbar.