# Scrollview doesn't show scrollbar always - android?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I have bellow `xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollProvince"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#434A54"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInternalTitleProvince"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/VInternalItemProvince"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="@color/Withe"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am using from this `xml` in `spinner` but don't work `android:fadeScrollbars="false"`.

I see bellow link but don't work yet :

[How to always show scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702502/how-to-always-show-scrollbar)

Comment: Use `android:fillViewport="true"`  and `android:scrollBars ="vertical"`

Comment: @ Piyush.Don't work .

Comment: Two Scrolls not working together , like you have spinner and Also Each Spinner  item also have ScrollView two,

Comment: I removed scrollView and add this android:fadeScrollbars="false" to spinner but don't work yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```