# Android: Scrollview shadow view by default

Tags: android, scrollview

Android scrollview shadow event if scrolling

I want scrollview visible shadow by default

How i can ?

xml :

```
<ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
                    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Can you please post an image of your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

use in xml `android:scrollbars` property for it

UPDATE

with `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` you can set scrollbar ever shown

Comment: add in your question your `xml` layout

Comment: explain more details what you have in your scrollview. Could you ever scroll?

Comment: in scrollview is shadow. this shadow visible on scroll down or up. by default this shadow invisible. i want this shadow without scroll visible

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702502/how-to-always-show-scrollbar/6558433). other, i dont know, how to help