# How to make recyclerview scrollbar always visible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollbar

I need to make `RecyclerView` Scrollbar always visible.
Scrollbar hiding is the default feature of `RecyclerView`. How can I do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you find how to make it ?

Comment: android:fadeScrollbars="true" use this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is about scrollview, but I think it will work on recyclerview also.

[How to always show scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702502/how-to-always-show-scrollbar)